# Why does my Sub take a varying amount of time to run?

Tags: excel, vba, time, execution

I am new to programming, and I am trying to write a routine on Excel VBA but ran into an issue with execution time.

I am running the same Sub 20 times to process 20 files of identical formats, so I expect the execution time to be similar.

While it typically takes about 30s to run a file, I found that sometimes it took 1000+s to run one. I don't think it is an issue with any specific file, because the anomalous file is different each time.

Why is this so?

The part of the code that has this issue is:

```
    'Add a new sheet called rETR to contain the results for rETR = Y*17*0.5
    'All cells between C2 and XR481 contain useful data
    With ThisWorkbook
        .Sheets.Add.Name = "rETR"
        Set rETR = Sheets("rETR")
        Set Y = Sheets("YII")
        For Each Cell In Y.Range("C2:XR481")
            myVal = Cell.value * 17 * 0.5
            rETR.Cells(Cell.Row, Cell.Column).value = myVal
        Next Cell
    End With
    
    'Create new sheet to contain "template" data, which area of interest is further reduced
    Sheets.Add
    
    'Reduce rETR data to the range in the template 
    'wbMPBtemp has previously been defined as a Workbook
    Set wbMPBtemp = Workbooks.Open(sPath & "MPB_temp.xlsx")

    'copy all the template data from that workbook into current workbook
    wbMPBtemp.Sheets("MPB_temp").Copy Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

    'rename the template sheet to "MPB_temp"
    ActiveSheet.Name = "MPB_temp"
    
    'close the original template workbook
    wbMPBtemp.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    Set MPB_AOI = Sheets("MPB_temp")
    
    'Reduce rETR to the AOI range based on the template
    'Create a new sheet to contain the rETR data reduced to new AOI range
    With ThisWorkbook
        .Sheets.Add.Name = "MPB-only_rETR"
        Set rETR_MPB = Sheets("MPB-only_rETR")
        rETR.Activate
        rETR.Range("C2:XR481").Select
        For Each Cell In Selection
            If Not MPB_AOI.Cells(Cell.Row, Cell.Column).value = "" Then
                rETR_MPB.Cells(Cell.Row, Cell.Column).value = Cell.value
            Else
                rETR_MPB.Cells(Cell.Row, Cell.Column).value = ""
            End If
        Next Cell
    End With
```

I attempted to shorten the execution time with the following ways:

- Defining the same group of variables in one line
- Turning off multiple Excel functions (as follows) at the beginning of the code, and turn them back on after running the code.

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False 
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks =False
```

Is there any other way that I should look into to shorten the execution time?

Comment: Turning off the Screen and Calc will help. It's likely turning off Event handling will also help (with the caveat that, if you have large loops it's wise to yield to OS with DoEvents periodically if you do so). Turning off Status bar and Page breaks won't help. That all aside though, without seeing your code, it's hard to just 'guess' at what might the cause.

Comment: [Without code, it is very hard to help you](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/)